# How to right-align Icon for an adaptive card's action?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to work out how to align icon to the right in my Action.OprnUrl's text
[image: preview]

In https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/ with card layout:

```json
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Publish Adaptive Card Schema"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Description",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "View",
            "url": "https://adaptivecards.io",
            "iconUrl": "data:image/png;base64,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"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.5"
}
```

sample data:

```json
{
    "title": "Publish Adaptive Card Schema",
    "description": "Description",
    "viewUrl": "https://adaptivecards.io"
}
```

According to [MS Teams Store guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/teams-store-validation-guidelines), it is possible
[image: MicrosoftExample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got an update from engineering team that if we use "iconUrl" property, we do not have any way to align the icon to the right side.

As an alternative solution,
I have tested the way suggested by Hilton and it is working fine for me with below JSON:

```
 {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Publish Adaptive Card Schema"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Description",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "View ",
            "url": "https://adaptivecards.io",
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4"
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mark - We have updated the documentation as well here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/teams-store-validation-guidelines#bots-1

Answer (score 1):

We have tried to test the provided card in https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/ but not able to see any property to align the icon in right side of text on the open URL button:

[image]

As per documentation we can add the "pop-out icon" in the bot response action button but looks like it is not:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/teams-store-validation-guidelines#bots-1

Comment: We will check with engineering team and let you know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but it looks like it -might- work to use Unicode for this, e.g. something like the following character:  (you can just copy-paste this into the actual "title" property. Here's a list of some possible unicode arrows, if this works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)